# c# int.tryParse nullable ints how to?

Tags: c#, asp.net, null, int

I need to sometimes set the value of an int to null and sometimes to an actual value.
The problem is I need to store that value in the SAME variable not create another.

```
int? year;
if(something)
   year = null;
else
   int.tryParse("some string", out year);
```

"some string" is always a valid int but the problem is I can't use int.tryParse on int?
How to get around that?

Comment: `"some string"` is never a valid int. (Except perhaps when using Eldritch culture)

Comment: No. I will actually have an int value there, it comes from dropdownlist.SelectedItem.Value which comes back as a string

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use int.TryParse with nullable int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390750/how-to-use-int-tryparse-with-nullable-int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Convert.ToInt32(year).

Comment: but this one still throws if string not empty and not a number.

Comment: Simplest way. thanks. The DB will make sure its always a number coming in and will do a try catch just to be safe

Answer (score 9):

If your string will always be a valid integer, you should just use the [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx) method.

```
year = int.Parse("some string");
```

In the case that it’s not a valid integer, you will get a `FormatException` or `OverflowException` (unlike [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7), which merely returns `false`).

Comment: and it always can be done in two simple steps. if performance is an issue here, Parse will be inferior

Comment: @MareInfinitus: I doubt that it’s significantly less efficient than `TryParse` (which still needs to perform validation). It may be less efficient than a manual implementation that skips all validation checks, but it’s usually not worth the trouble.

Comment: according to some benchmarking i have seen it is definitly slower by magnitudes. here it is: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ianhu/archive/2005/12/19/505702.aspx    in the conclusion

Comment: @MareInfinitus: It will be significantly slower if it throws (as is the case with throwing exceptions in general), not if it always succeeds. I’ve checked the internal implementations of `Parse` and `TryParse`, and apart from throwing vs returning false, they’re identical.

Comment: @MareInfinitus: From that article: “All of these functions take about the same time with good data.” The results of the tests with the bad data are irrelevant, since the OP guaranteed that the string will always be valid.

Comment: i prefer generic, reuseable solutions over "will work for this case" approaches. just a matter of taste though

Comment: @MareInfinitus: If the OP said that the string will *always* be valid, then `Parse` is the correct way to go. If you think one should always use `TryParse`, then that’s just your personal opinion.

Comment: @MareInfinitus The choice is about intent. Using `Parse` says "This will always be valid. If it's invalid, we have a bug, so no need to handle that case." whereas `TryParse` says "It can sometimes be invalid, and I've added explicit error handling for it". In most cases the right choice is quite obvious, and since the OP said that the value is guaranteed to be a valid int, `Parse` is clearly the better choice here.

Comment: as stated, this is my preference, as I try to avoid "works here and now" approaches.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Good explanation re “intent”. I need to learn to factor that into my justifications more often.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
public class NullInt
{
    public void ParseInt(string someString, ref int? someInt)
    {
        int i;

        if (int.TryParse(someString, out i))
        {
            someInt = i;
        }
    }
}
```

and used somewhat like:

```
NullInt someInt = new NullInt();
int? targetInt = null;
someInt.ParseInt("42", ref targetInt);
```

Comment: Just because you didn't get an upvote, please don't go and downvote all the other option. We are all giving up our time to help people out because other people help us out. If you don't like my answer, just commment below it. And if someone give a stupid answer, then down vote to indicate that it is a bad answer

Comment: it may look i was this, but i did not, as you can see from that I did not loose any reputation. (think you get -1 for downvoting, or?) ... if i think somewhat is broken, i leave an comment on that. and you can see many comments by me here... 490 entering here, 490 leaving here, no problem for me, just wanted to leave the solution that seems to be the best for me.

Comment: no problem, as i wondered myself who would do that. discussion is always better than plain downvote, as i believe everybody can learn something, even he is skeet or gossman. and if anybody thinks something is wrong in what i believe is the best solution, i definitly want to know that.

Answer (score 0):

If "some string" is always a valid int, then you COULD just convert it to an int, using [System.Convert.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx) or [System.Int32.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

int.tryParse returns a boolean, not just the out value - you can do this also:

```
int year;
int? finalYear;
if(int.TryParse("some string", out year))
    finalYear = year;
```

otherwise, if "some string" will always return a valid int, why not do

```
int? year = int.Parse("some string");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static int? AsInt(this string input)
    {
        int number;
        if (int.TryParse(input, out number))
        {
            return number;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage: `year = someString.AsInt();`

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work also:

```
int? year;
    if (something)
       year = null;
    else
    {
       int _year;
       int.TryParse(year.SelectedItem.Value, out _year);
       year = _year;
    }
```

Comment: the return value if tryparse should be checked i believe.

Comment: Using `TryParse` without checking the result is only a good idea if you want the value to become `default(T)`, which isn't the case here. You're just hiding a bug if that happens.

Answer (score -2):

Add in some error detection:

```
try
{
   year = int.Parse("some string");
}
catch()
{
   year = null;
}
```