# How to check if string is number and assign it to nullable int?

Tags: c#

I have nullable int[] and string.

```
string someStr = "123"; 

int? siteNumber = null;
string siteName= null;
```

At some point I need to check if a string is number.

For this purpose I tryed this:

```
if (int.TryParse(someStr, out siteNumber)) 
    { } 
else 
    siteName = siteDescription;
```

But because siteNumber is nullable I get  this error:

```
cannot convert from 'out int?' to 'out int'
```

How can I check if string is number and if it is I  need to assign it to nullable int?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390750/how-to-use-int-tryparse-with-nullable-int

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a string into a nullable int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45030/how-to-parse-a-string-into-a-nullable-int)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your custom method for doing this.

```
public int? TryParseNullableValues(string val)
{
    int outValue;
    return int.TryParse(val, out outValue) ? (int?)outValue : null;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use an intermediate variable because the `out` parameters types should match fully.

```
int siteNumberTemp;
if (int.TryParse(someStr, out siteNumberTemp)) 
{
   siteNumber = siteNumberTemp;
} 
else 
   siteName = siteDescription;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without using another variable, because the type of `out` arguments has to match the parameter exactly.

```
 string someStr = "123";
 int? siteNumber = null;

 int tmp;
 if (!int.TryParse(someStr.Trim(), out tmp))
 {
     //Do something if not parsed
 }
 else
 {
     siteNumber = tmp;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is simply use this function to convert string to int no matter it is nullable or not. This custom function will handle it.

```
public static Int32? CustomConvertToInt32(Object obj)
{
    string _strData = CustomConvertToStringOrNull(obj);

    Int32? _Nullable = null;
    Int32 _data;

    if (Int32.TryParse(_strData, out _data))
    {
        _Nullable = _data;
    }
    return _Nullable;
}

 public static string CustomConvertToStringOrNull(Object obj)
    {
        string _Nullable = null;
        if (obj != null)
        {
            if (obj.ToString().Trim() == "" || obj.ToString().Trim().ToLower() == "n/a")
            {
                _Nullable = null;
            }
            else
            {
                _Nullable = obj.ToString().Trim();
            }
        }

        return _Nullable;
    }


int? siteNumber = CustomConvertToInt32(someStr);
```